# Math is extra italic in Chrome with local STIX fonts

Tags: support, mathjax

I noticed that, on the same computer, math formulas in  [Variant of the Lévy hierarchy on formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67233/variant-of-the-levy-hierarchy-on-formulas) are extra italic in Google Chrome 14.0.835.186 and correct in Firefox 6.0.2. I am using Mac OS X 10.7.1. By "extra italic" I mean that some sort of software postprocessing is causing the fonts to be even more slanted than they would naturally be. So various upright characters such as parentheses and capital Greek letters end up slanted and already-slanted lowercase letters are grotesquely over-slanted.

I have diagnosed this to having the STIX fonts installed locally. Since it's the same computer, it's not an issue of *different* fonts being installed. It seems Chrome is just handling the fonts poorly.

I was able to diagnose this by disabling the STIX fonts in "Font Book".

I see there have been several other strange rendering problems in Chrome, but this one seems to be unreported.

Here is a screenshot; notice even the parentheses are slanted.

[image: Screenshot of slanted fonts]

Comment: I have the same problem. It appears to be specific to Safari and Chrome (i.e. the WebKit browsers).

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/950/are-the-formulas-not-parsing-in-64-bit-chrome-or-is-it-just-me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I diagnosed this to having the STIX fonts installed locally. Unfortunately I am prevented by the software from marking the bug as completed. Also, very strangely,  despite having 10k rep (!) I had to file a CAPTCHA for this answer. Aren't those supposed to be disabled for users with even a modest amount of rep?

I am also prevented by the software from accepting this answer for some time, so please imagine it has been accepted.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I have diagnosed it in a previous post. You can disable the fonts.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what it looks like in Chrome (current rev) on Windows 7, screenshot below:

---

[image]